# Envers 4.2.x adds a record to the AUD table even if there are no changes

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers, post-update

I'm using Hibernate Envers 4.2.21.FINAL. As I want to track only some properties' changes, I added the annotation

```
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
```

on them. The flag column "propname_MOD" is correctly created, but the problem is that when I save an object, all the MOD flags are set to true, and not only for the attribute I modified.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that in the class `org.hibernate.envers.event.EnversPostUpdateEventListenerImpl`,
when the following object is instantiated

```
AuditWorkUnit workUnit = new ModWorkUnit(
    event.getSession(),event.getPersister().getEntityName(),getAuditConfiguration(),
    event.getId(),event.getPersister(),newDbState,event.getOldState() );
```

`event.getOldState()` is null, but IMO it should be not null. This is why Envers is adding a new revision each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in fact related to the `event.getOldState()` being `null`.

It was due to the `saveOrUpdate` method of Hibernate, which perceives the entity from JSF as detached.
I now use `merge` instead of `saveOrUpdate` and Envers correctly stores the _MOD fields to true or false.